# How to create Sprite with animation?

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, sprite

Is it possible to create a sprite with animation instead of a texture? Is there a way to use an animation just like a texture so that it can be used on a sprite? sorry, I'm new to Java and Libgdx.

Comment: Just a note...you have not accepted answers on your past 10 questions. You might get better responses and more help if you do. It's also better to revise your old question rather than repeat it over and over with minor changes. Your question will actually get *more* attention that way because it gets bumped and there will be more discussion surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an animated sprite, using an image containing the frames of the animation.
[Here is the libgdx documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation) that explains it very well.